# How to clear the previous inputs?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app..there are 2 activities i.e.
page1 and page2.
flow is page1-->page2

On page1, i have used many checkboxes. After selection of one checkbox, when i presses the "next" button, it goes to page2 activity showing the result but when i presses back button and select another checkbox, it is still showing the same result on page2 i.e. of previous selection.
I m new to android.please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
i thik you should mentain page1 using 

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
   // here you checkyour checked checkbox items and make it unchecked 

    }
```

this mayhelps you

Comment: Sir, i have used above code now.On pressing back button. checkboxes are unchecked but it still giving me the same output aftr checking another checkbox. I havent programmed on checkbox in my app. I m just using that if a checkbox is checked then put value particular to that checkbox in int variable n m passing that variable to another activity.

Comment: no not in press button but on main class used it , its override method, make here checked checkbox unceched

Comment: Thanks sir, Done :) its Running

Answer (score 1):

I thought you were having your own back button..if you're using the phone's back button, try this code to finish the current activity and go to the previous activity [this is to be added to page2 activity]:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If you want to implement your own back button, under the listener for the button, use an intent to start an activity to go back to the previous activity..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Page2ActivityFileName.this, Page1ActivityFileName.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: No, i didn't use intent on back button.

Comment: Please guide me how to use Back button to start an activity?

Answer (score 0):

See you're probably using startactivity(intent); whereas in this case you should use startactivityforresult(intent); Hope you get it, if not drop a comment I'll elaborate my answer with some code.